# Python Pandas multiple occurrences of a row in dataframe 1 into new column of dataframe 2

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 Pandas DataFrames in Python:

**df1**

```
File    Repeated
   A           4
   B           2
   C           3
```

and **df2**

```
 Test_Q Auto_logger
 Termin        -314
 Termin          77
 Termin          12
 Termin         267
AR_test          36
AR_test          89
Tap_wtr         105
Tap_wtr         719
Tap_wtr          62
```

The **Repeated** column of **df1** shows the number of rows in **df2** where the first column is the same - call this number `n`. I am trying to put `n` identical rows showing the File name into **df2**. Since there are multiple files, I need to do this for all "n" values from **df1**.

**Here is the output that I need to assemble:**

**df3**

```
File  Test_Q Auto_logger
   A  Termin        -314
   A  Termin          77
   A  Termin          12
   A  Termin         267
   B AR_test          36
   B AR_test          89
   C Tap_wtr         105
   C Tap_wtr         719
   C Tap_wtr          62
```

If I try to do this in a loop, it is very slow, since there are many files.

How could I add in multiple identical rows from one dataframe into another dataframe like I showed above?

EDIT 1:
The `Repeated` column could have duplicated values, but that does not **need** to be the case.

EDIT 2:
To produce the above dataframes, copy them to the clipboard and then save them to *.csv files using:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard() #after hiliting and copying df1 from this post
df.to_csv('df1.csv', index=False)
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')

dfb = pd.read_clipboard() #after hiliting and copying df2 from this post
dfb.to_csv('df2.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
```

Comment: I think i understand what you're after, but would there be duplicate values in the Repeated column?

Comment: Hi, I should have made that clear. Yes, you're right, there could be duplicate values in the `Repeated` column, but that does not **need** to be the case. Added this to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.repeat` can come in handy here:

```
>>> df3 = df2.copy()
>>> df3["File"] = np.repeat(df1.File.values, df1.Repeated.values)
>>> df3
   Auto_logger   Test_Q File
0         -314   Termin    A
1           77   Termin    A
2           12   Termin    A
3          267   Termin    A
4           36  AR_test    B
5           89  AR_test    B
6          105  Tap_wtr    C
7          719  Tap_wtr    C
8           62  Tap_wtr    C
```

where `np.repeat` is basically the vectorized version of

```
[v for val, num in zip(df1.File, df1.Repeated) for v in [val]*num]
```

Comment: Great answer! I did not know about `np.repeat()`.